# Vault secrets list permission denied

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I can't understand how `secrets list` works.
I have policy with path permission.

```
path "sys/mounts/*" {
capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list","sudo"]
}
```

I can run enable and disable flags

```
$ vault secrets enable -path=Test kv
Success! Enabled the kv secrets engine at: Test/
$ vault secrets disable Test
Success! Disabled the secrets engine (if it existed) at: Test/
```

But I can't run list or move

```
vault secrets list
Error listing secrets engines: Error making API request.

URL: GET http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/mounts
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied

vault secrets move Test Test2
Error moving secrets engine Test/ to Test2/: Error making API request.

URL: POST http://localhost/v1/sys/remount
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied
```

Its not a file system permission issue, after change admin-token to root-token everything work fine. So anyone can explain me this behavior ?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/2961

Comment: Nice, that's work. But why i must  additionally use `policy`? `capabilities` is not 
enough ?

Comment: I'm confused too. I couldn't find any information in documentation about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
path "sys/mounts" {
capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

The command are performed on `sys/mounts`, not `sys/mounts/*`

Comment: Thanks. Everything what I need is `capabilities = ["read"]` on path `sys/mounts`, instead of not clean `policy` properties

Answer (score 0):

Just to add. All the secret backend paths which can be allowed or disallowed for a particular token are listed on this web page https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/index.html

When you get permission denied to any of the URL. You need to search that URL on this page. And you will get the whole information about that system backend. e.g. You can search both "sys/remount" and "sys/mounts"